# how to increase value in Realtime Database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

```
 const dataFromDbUser = admin.database().ref('Base/' + 'users/'+ userId);

 dataFromDbUser.on('value',(item)=>{
 item.val().money //10
 })
```

how can i increase the value of money? Thank you

using node.js

this is what the base looks like

```
Base:{
   users:{
      22333443:{
         money:10
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a task for `ServerValue.increment`, so I recommend reading the documentation on [atomically incrementing a value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments)?

This also works from the Admin SDKs. So if you're having a problem making it work, please edit your question to show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: admin.database().ref('Base/' + 'users/'+ userId).update({
    money: admin.database.ServerValue.increment(10)
  });  works, thanks a lot)))